# How can I join models in ExtJS?

Tags: json, database, join, extjs, model

In ExtJS 6.02, I would like to join 2 or more models into a single store.

**1 to 1 relationship:**

---

Given users that can only be associated with a single user detail row in DB:

```json
"users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Philip J. Fry",
      "userDetail": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Hubert Farnsworth",
      "userDetail": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Turanga Leela",
      "userDetail": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Amy Wong",
      "userDetail": 4
    }
]
```

```json
"usersDetails": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "jfry@a.com",
      "sex": "m"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "hubert@a.com",
      "sex": "m"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "email": "leela@a.com",
      "sex": "f"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "email": "amy@a.com",
      "sex": "m"
    }
]
```

I would like to have this on the store:

```json
"users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Philip J. Fry",
      "email": "jfry@a.com",
      "sex": "m"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Hubert Farnsworth",
      "email": "hubert@a.com",
      "sex": "m"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Turanga Leela",
      "email": "leela@a.com",
      "sex": "f"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Amy Wong",
      "email": "amy@a.com",
      "sex": "m"
    }
]
```

**1 to many relationship:**

---

Given users that can have multiple posts in BD:

```json
"users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Philip J. Fry",
      "userDetail": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Hubert Farnsworth",
      "userDetail": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Turanga Leela",
      "userDetail": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Amy Wong",
      "userDetail": 4
    }
]
```

```json
"posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user": 1,
      "title": "Post 1 title",
      "body": "Post 1 body"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "user": 1,
      "title": "Post 2 title",
      "body": "Post 2 body"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "user": 2,
      "title": "Post 3 title",
      "body": "Post 3 body"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "user": 3,
      "title": "Post 4 title",
      "body": "Post 4 body"
    }
]
```

I would like to have a store containing:

```json
"items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Philip J. Fry",
      "posts": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Post 1 title",
            "body": "Post 1 body"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Post 2 title",
            "body": "Post 2 body"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Hubert Farnsworth",
      "posts": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "user": 2,
            "title": "Post 3 title",
            "body": "Post 3 body"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Turanga Leela",
      "userDetail": 3,
      "posts": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "user": 3,
            "title": "Post 4 title",
            "body": "Post 4 body"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Amy Wong",
      "posts": []
    }
]
```

**Many to 1 relationship:**

---

This is actually my actual issue, I have a DB table with multiple items that each can only match a single item in another table.
Should be same as 1 to many.

**Many to many relationship:**

---

Basicly same as 1 to many I guess?

I have seem this solution: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hs9&view/editor it doesn't cover everything and maybe there's a better option.

Comment: Do you actually have different endpoints that feed you this data, or is it more of a situation like you're wanting to do quasi-SQL statements with disparate sources of data you have available?

Comment: Hi @incutonez, yes they are different endpoints. The thing is that the backend is legacy, it can only return a flat JSON (an array of objects) so no nested items. Also the backend API is all in PL/SQL and has many other limitations, so the idea is to move more things to frontend and see if it works better this way. This is not a public API and I can't share actual real code.

Comment: So help us out here... what is your current thought for attacking this problem?  Ext JS does not have a concept of "joining" models into one store.  Whatever the store's model is, that's the signature all of the models within it will have.  You're going to have to create some sort of intermediate step that massages your data how you want it.  I would probably create an API endpoint that stitches this information together, but I don't know if that's something you can do... forcing the UI to do all of it is never a good idea.

Comment: @incutonez One idea I had was to merge the models, like adding extra fields in a model or creating a model that joins the models. One thing I don't understand is that since I have set relations between the models, I should be able to for example having a user, obtain all his posts, but it's only possible to access the posts if they come bundled with the user data on the API response, I can't find any way to get the posts.

Comment: Well because your post data is all lumped together with other user information, it doesn't make sense to load them individually... also, when a grid loads, you typically don't make extra calls per record to get more data... your endpoint normally returns all the data you need for the grid.  If you know all of the endpoints ahead of time, you can call them all, stitch the data together and feed that to your grid's store, or like I said, create an API endpoint that does this for you, and it returns the data the way you need it.

Comment: @incutonez Sure, it would be better to have the API handle this, but unfortunately it's impossible, I tried many things to circumvent the limitations, and I can't update the system we use to handle the API calls myself.

Comment: I'm still confused about the JSON you posted... those are individual endpoints?  Like GET `api/users`, GET `api/users/details`, etc.?

Comment: @incutonez Yes, those are different endpoints, the 1 to 1 relationship could be done on backend, but I would like to have an option to threat it on front end. But the other ones I can only obtain a flat array of objects, so it's not possible to have a user and all his posts in the same API response. I'm investigating if it's possible to get nested data, but by now no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230737/discussion-between-incutonez-and-user5507535).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Sencha support:

> The concept of joining records doesn't really exist within ExtJS but
> you can, by making use of renderers, access and print record
> association data.
>
> I have a simple fiddle of your example above showing you how you may
> achieve this. Please note that dynamic loading of association (which
> you have in your example) makes using renderers a bit tricky, but not
> impossible, as the loading of the association info is asynchronous in
> nature and the renderer cannot wait for the response. The work around
> is to refresh the entire grid when all association stores have
> finished loading.
>
> https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3d1v&view/editor